# What proportion of UK civilians killed in the first and second world wars were women and children?

Tags: world-war-two, world-war-one, united-kingdom, statistics, victims

I recently learnt that the number of UK civilians killed in the first world war is around 2,000. This seems surprisingly low but understandable when we realize that the UK wasn't subject to a land invasion and air warfare was then very primitive.

However, during the second world war it is the much higher figure of around 70,000. Although again the UK wasn't invaded it was subject to massive Nazi bombing raids. And the much higher figure will be due to this.

I've looked online for a breakdown of these figures into men, women and children but found nothing. If anyone has this breakdown to hand or know of a reference please let me know.

Comment: Airborne warfare was a new idea in WW1, and most bombing raids used [airships](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/education/resources/zeppelin-raids/).

Comment: General numbers for WW1 civilians [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_United_Kingdom_during_the_First_World_War#Casualties): *The 1922 War Office report detailed the deaths of 1,260 civilians and 310 military personnel due to air and sea bombardment the home islands.[179] Losses at sea were 908 civilians and 63 fisherman killed by U-boat attacks.[180]* The 1922 primary source might give more info, but is [unavailable at the moment](https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/statistics-of-military-effort-of-british-empire).

Comment: Unsourced number on children killed during the Blitz [here](https://www.iwm.org.uk/history/growing-up-in-the-second-world-war#:~:text=At%20the%20start%20of%20the,killed%20and%207%2C622%20seriously%20wounded.)  *At the start of the Blitz, London was attacked on 57 successive nights and later there were heavy raids on other major cities and ports. During the Blitz 7,736 children were killed and 7,622 seriously wounded.*

Comment: During WWI, the UK population was circa 46.0 million and circa 6.2 million mobilized military personnel, mostly men, all adult. Subtracting the 6.2 million adult men from UK demographic figures would provide figures for women, children, and non-mobilized men. Dividing the fatalities proportionally among those civilians would provide a reasonable estimate, but obviously not real statistics. Note also that actual statistics are disputed between sources, and depend on historians' methodologies.

Comment: @Henry Brainfart.... comment deleted.

Comment: @Steve: I had a similar idea, but I know that during the blitz, which targeted London more than anywhere else, the children were evacuated out of London. This is going to skew the stats given by your estimate to more adults and fewer children. Thxs for commenting.